# simple url format for crawling youtube categories?

Tags: php, python, curl, youtube, web-crawler

Is there a simple form like http://www.youtube.com/category/horror or even something with a simple get parameter that would allow one get to the different youtube category homes?

Note I am aware of the api...I am asking about a direct url format that would allow one visit different categories with python or php or something.

Any tools that already do this are ofcourse very welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youtube category homes?
Take a look to see if the following types of pages are what you're looking for:

- [Youtube Category Home - Autos & Vehicles](http://www.youtube.com/categories?c=2)
- [Youtube Category Home - Gaming](http://www.youtube.com/categories?c=20) (Hurray!)
- Both use the 'c' variable to denote a category.. The URL is youtube.com/categories .

If you want, the second best option to browse the category (by "Most watched") is:

- [Gaming (page 1 of 'most watched')](http://www.youtube.com/categories?c=20&p=1)  ... uses a p=0 variable and up to specify which page of results.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I think the OP probably wants to look them up by name. Looks like you could scrape some of the name/number mappings off of http://youtube.com/categories, if nothing else.

Comment: @Mu-Mind Thanks for the help-- I can see that, but I can only wait to hear from what the asker says too.. :/

Comment: ..this in itself is great!...@Mu-Mind is right that I would prefer to look them up by name but this is a great start I'm sure it shouldn't be too bad to create the name/number mappings. Thanks!..lets see if someone has a way of getting it without scraping..:)